# How to drop captions while extracting text from PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I am trying to run LDA on a set of pdf files to access the major topics out of those files. I am able to extract the data from pdf using pdfminer.

Problem 1: But the problem is that the captions and descriptions given to the diagrams and images in the pdf are not useful for me. How can I remove the unwanted portion from pdf.

Problem 2: Before I put run LDA model I want to remove all the newline characters and punctuation signs from the text.

The code that I am using to extract data is as follows:

```
from pdfminer import .layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextBoxHorizontal
from pdfminer.layout import LTFigure
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
import gensim
from gensim import corpora
from pprint import pprint
document = open('C:/Users/kaurj/Desktop/File1.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(document):
interpreter.process_page(page)    
layout = device.get_result() 

for element in layout:
    if isinstance(element, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
        values = element.get_text()
        print (values)
```

The File1 used in the code is embedded here:-

[ https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=DA6170EA591F0D07&resid=DA6170EA591F0D07%21106&authkey=ALua6WdCD7Ct6zo&em=2"]

Comment: Please post what you have tried with codes and errors.

Answer (score 1):

If the captions themselves follow some sort of pattern (as they would in scientific texts), you can remove them with regular expressions -- see this [link](https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub) for a quick overview and [this one](https://regexr.com/) to try out regular expressions that match this pattern (I assume they would start with "Figure" followed by a number, and a string of indeterminate length -this makes it a little tricky- and most likely a newline character or other indicator, the details depend on the parser and document you use).

For cleaning the text, you have several options. Gensim has a few tools, as does NLTK. The simplest version is using `replace`, a built-in python function.  `textdocument.replace(""\n", "")`and repeat for each character you want to switch out with another (or in this case, with "", i.e. nothing). I personally would recommend the [clean-text](https://pypi.org/project/clean-text/) package, which is quite flexible and does most of the work for you.

An example:

```
from cleantext import clean

text = "I am a sample text. 
I have -many- weird characters, such as , . # and some numbers,
4335 and 12 more. 
Here is a newline character \n and a $ sign. 
Some words are CAPITALIZED and this is an email address: hello@example.com"


clean(text,
        fix_unicode=True,               # fix various unicode errors
        lower=True,                     # lowercase text
        no_line_breaks=True,           # strip line breaks 
        no_emails=True,                # replace all email addresses with a special token
        no_numbers=True,               # replace all numbers with a special token
        no_digits=True,                # replace all digits with a special token
        no_currency_symbols=True,      # replace all currency symbols with a special token
        no_punct=True,                 # fully remove punctuation
        replace_with_email="",
        replace_with_number="",
        replace_with_digit="",
        replace_with_currency_symbol="",
        lang="en") 

Out[3]: 'i am a sample text i have many weird characters such as and some numbers and more here is a newline character and a sign some words are capitalized and this is an email address'
```